# Offset в методе wall.get vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я получаю список записей методом `wall.get`, далее смещаю `offset` на кол-во полученных записей, но как только группа выкладывает новый пост, старый `offset` уже не валидин и я получаю повторяшки.

Хотелось бы говорить не смещение, а дату последнего полученного паста. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Можешь получать записи с пересечением и удалять повторяющиеся.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы запрашиваете список записей на стене, ответ выглядит примерно так:

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": число,
    "items": [
      {
        "date": 1499452661,
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Где `date` - время в `unixtime`. Вы можете создать свой JSONArray, затем пробежаться по массиву items и добавить оттуда все JSONObject-ы записей, которые вам нужны, сравнивая их дату с нужной вам. Время в unixtime и обратно легко переводится на любом языке программирования.